# Simplify QCD Lagrangian

Tags: standard-model, charge, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

How we can derive the electric charge of the field theory for each field?

- For example lets say that we have the u-quarks (3-colors) and electron that we know that has charge -e) free Lagrangian
  $$\mathscr{L}=\sum_{colors}\bar{\psi}_{u_i}(i\gamma_{\mu}\mathscr{D}^{\mu}-m_u)\psi_{u_i}+\bar{\psi}_e(i\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}-m_e)\psi_e-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{4}G_{\mu\nu}^aG^{a\mu\nu}$$

I try to couple the terms that they have the form $\bar{\psi}q\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi$ and I get that the u-quarks, in this theory, must have $q_u=+\frac{1}{3}e$, is that right?

Also how can we find the interaction Hamiltonian for the non-relativistic u-quark with a homogeneous magnetic field $B$?

Comment: You don't "derive" the charge. You must *set* it when constructing the gauge covariant derivative for $A_\mu$ acting on the quarks. The second question about the interaction Hamiltonian is both unrelated and unclear.

Comment: Yes i know that the charge is a parameter of the theory , but if want to guess what would be the charge of the u-quark know that mini-QCD theory, there is no way that i can derive it ? Like the total charge of the field do be zero , or something like that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Without experimental results *telling* you that the quarks have a third of the electron charge, you could let the quarks have arbitrary charge.

Comment: In our class today , our teacher ask as to guess,what is the correct value of charge of q for the resulting theory to also describe the electromagnetic phenomena of the u-quarks.And we were working on the Lagrangian above... so I don't know that what I'm trying to clear in my mind..